# Get the list of items matching a specific pattern of string

Tags: c#

I have a `C#` model `LedgerEntity`.

```
public class LedgerEntity
{
     public string AccountNumber{get;set;}
     public string Accountlevel{get;set;}
     public string AccountName{get;set;}
}
```

Also I have a list of items of that model class like below

```
List<LedgerEntity> items=new List<LedgerEntity>();

items=[
{"AccountNumber":"07-01-GRP_10095-81120000","AccountLevel":"Group","AccountName":"JPM"},
{"AccountNumber":"G3-80-GRP_10895-8112SLC0","AccountLevel":"Group","AccountName":"CIT"},
{"AccountNumber":"1C-MULTI-2851170-MULTI_8113xxxx","AccountLevel":"Group","AccountName":"BON"},
{"AccountNumber":"07-MULTI-MULTI_NONCORE-MULTI","AccountLevel":"Group","AccountName":"CUK"}}
]
```

My requirement is some thing like this.
I need to get all the records which contains

```
"GRP_*8112(* can have any value like 10095- or 10895- etc...)" in `AccountNumber. Then remove "GRP_" from the record and add "70" in front of the 3rd hyphen.

Example: 07-01-GRP_10095-81120000 --> 07-01-1009570-81120000
```

also update the `Accountlevel` of that matched records from `Group`  to `Individual`.

My expected output is something like this.

```
matchedItems=[
{"AccountNumber":"07-01-1009570-81120000","AccountLevel":"Individual","AccountName":"JPM"},
{"AccountNumber":"G3-80-1089570-8112SLC0","AccountLevel":"Individual","AccountName":"CIT"},
{"AccountNumber":"1C-MULTI-2851170-MULTI_8113xxxx","AccountLevel":"Group","AccountName":"BON"},
{"AccountNumber":"07-MULTI-MULTI_NONCORE-MULTI","AccountLevel":"Group","AccountName":"CUK"}}
]
```

Please help me on this.

Comment: `var ledgers = items.Where(x=> x.AccountNumber.Contains("10895-")).ToList();`

Comment: SO isn't here to design and/or implement things that you need to do. What have you tried?

Comment: @isRs i need to check GRP_*8112 not 10895.

Comment: I need to find matching records that contain GRP_*80112. and update that value by removing GRP_

Comment: @Meena You didn't answer my question. I didn't ask you what you need, but what you have tried to solve your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
    foreach (var item in items)
    {
        var grpIndex = item.AccountNumber.IndexOf("GRP_");
        if (grpIndex >= 0)
        {
            var numberIndex = item.AccountNumber.Substring(grpIndex + 4).IndexOf("8112");
            if (numberIndex >= 0)
            {
                item.AccountNumber = item.AccountNumber.Replace("GRP_", "");
                item.Accountlevel = "Individual";
                var i = 0;
                var counter = 0;
                foreach (var ch in item.AccountNumber)
                {
                    if (ch == '-') counter++;
                    if (counter == 3) break;
                    i++;
                }
                if (counter == 3) item.AccountNumber = item.AccountNumber.Insert(i, "70");
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you Serge, your code is working like a charm !!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

your problem can be solved with [Regex](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.match?view=net-5.0) with an expression like this for example:

```regex
(10(8|0)95)
```

You can use following code:

```cs
items.Where(item => Regex.IsMatch(item.AccountNumber, @"10(8|0)95)"))
```

Comment: I need to find matching records that contain GRP_*80112. and update that value by removing GRP_

Comment: You can try to use FileSystemName.MatchesSimpleExpression method in the System.IO.Enumeration namespace (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.enumeration.filesystemname.matchessimpleexpression?view=net-5.0), in order to use the wildcard and will be like :

```string text = "07-01-GRP_10095-81120000";

bool isMatch = FileSystemName.MatchesSimpleExpression("GRP_*80112", text);```